# Add On Hold or Flagged button to question filters

Tags: discussion, questions, flagging

Would it be feasible to add a 'Flagged' or 'On Hold' button next to the 'newest', 'frequent', 'unanswered' filter buttons in the question list?
It could bring greater attention to them, and help make sure they get addressed before they are forgotten.

Comment: This would be a feature request to Stack Exchange Administrators. We (Moderators) only monitor  & manage the questions and answers, and of course spam.

Comment: I figured that would be the process required to make the change, I thought it might be worth seeing if there is interest/agreement in the value of that kind of change among the community/moderators, or facilitate discussion on other options on the matter. Demonstrating support for a request probably goes a long way towards getting it noticed and implemented at the .se admin level too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Flagged questions are automatically brought to the community's attention:** little icons in the top strip (usually to the left of the "review" link) will light up and link to lists of flagged posts.

**The system already has a mechanism to identify questions on hold,** although it might not be too well known: use the advanced search option [closed:yes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes) and sort by newest.

Comment: Additionally, for those users with rep>10K, all this is available in the Moderator tools at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tools